# Show (inner) product of two infinite sums is convergent or divergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, inner-products

> Show that if ${ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{b_n}}$ absolutely convergent and ${ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n} }$ convergent then the inner product ${ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}{b_n} }$ is also convergent.
>
> Introductory Real Analysis by F. Dangello and M. Seyfried.

I feel like this could be proved using the Dirichlet's test but I did not know how to approach it from that direction. I also read something about Hadamard products on power series but I don't know if I could use it to prove my question. Furthermore, I read this question [Convergence of product of convergent series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2075511/convergence-of-product-of-convergent-series) but since I only have $b_n \ge 0$ the question is different.

My approach was to try to use the Cauchy condition stating that:

Since ${ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}}$ convergent thus $\forall \varepsilon \gt0, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} : \vert s_n -s_m\vert = \vert \sum_{k=m+1}^na_k \vert \lt \sqrt\varepsilon$ if $ n \gt m \gt n_0$.

Furthermore, ${ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{b_n}}$ (absolutely)convergent thus $\forall \varepsilon \gt0, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} : \vert s_n -s_m\vert = \vert \sum_{k=m+1}^nb_k \vert \lt \sqrt\varepsilon$ if $ n \gt m \gt n_0$.

Then, $\vert\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}\vert \vert\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{b_n} \vert = \vert \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}{b_n} \vert \lt \sqrt\varepsilon\sqrt\varepsilon= \varepsilon$. Hence ${ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}{b_n} }$ convergent.

I feel like I made a mistake in the last line where I multiplied both series, and that my approach is too simplistic. So is my approach correct? Or where did I make a mistake? And how would I go about to prove this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\{a_n\}$ is eventually bounded by one as $\sum a_n$ is convergent. Hence for $N$ large enough and $n \ge N$

$$\vert a_n b_n \vert \le \vert b_n\vert$$

Which implies that $\sum a_n b_n$ is absolutely convergent as $\sum b_n$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: $\{a_n\}$ converges to zero as $\sum a_n$ is convergent. Hence $\vert a_n \vert \le 1$ for $n$ large enough. *In analysis, bounded often means that the absolute value (or the norm more generally) is bounded.*

Answer (score 4):

That proof is not correct. It is *not* true in general that $$\left\vert\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}\right\vert\left\vert\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{b_n}\right\vert=\left\vert \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}{b_n}\right\vert.$$It is false even for finite sums:$$1=|1+0||0+1|\ne|1\times0+0\times1|=0.$$

Comment: José, the result asked in the question is indeed correct. what is not correct is the proof attempt in the question.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Yes. And the OP knows that the statement is correct; therefore, my assertion “That is not correct” can only be about the proof. But I will edit my answer.